# How to correctly set input based on value of key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Write a function named "sort_kvs" that takes a list/array of key-value stores as a parameter where each key-value store has keys "power", "purity", "strike", "ability", and "spin" all mapping to integer values. Sort the input based on the values at the key "purity".

```
function sort_kvs(lista){
    lista.sort(function(x){return x['purity']});
    return lista;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

function sort_kvs incorrect on input `[[{'strike': 11, 'power': 249, 'ability': 5, 'purity': 19, 'spin': 13}, {'strike': 18, 'power': 247, 'ability': 20, 'purity': 6, 'spin': 487}, {'strike': 11, 'power': 201, 'ability': -8, 'purity': 10, 'spin': 489}, {'strike': -17, 'power': 290, 'ability': 14, 'purity': 16, 'spin': 269}]]`

result: `[{'strike': -17, 'power': 290, 'ability': 14, 'purity': 16, 'spin': 269}, {'strike': 11, 'power': 201, 'ability': -8, 'purity': 10, 'spin': 489}, {'strike': 18, 'power': 247, 'ability': 20, 'purity': 6, 'spin': 487}, {'strike': 11, 'power': 249, 'ability': 5, 'purity': 19, 'spin': 13}]`

expected: `[{'strike': 18, 'power': 247, 'ability': 20, 'purity': 6, 'spin': 487}, {'strike': 11, 'power': 201, 'ability': -8, 'purity': 10, 'spin': 489}, {'strike': -17, 'power': 290, 'ability': 14, 'purity': 16, 'spin': 269}, {'strike': 11, 'power': 249, 'ability': 5, 'purity': 19, 'spin': 13}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort`'s callback accepts *two* parameters - one of which is one item you're comparing, and the other of which is the other item you're comparing it to. So, call `sort` with those two arguments, then access the `purity` property of each, and return the difference:

```js
const sort_kvs = arr => arr.sort((a, b) => a.purity - b.purity);

const input=[[{'strike':11,'power':249,'ability':5,'purity':19,'spin':13},{'strike':18,'power':247,'ability':20,'purity':6,'spin':487},{'strike':11,'power':201,'ability':-8,'purity':10,'spin':489},{'strike':-17,'power':290,'ability':14,'purity':16,'spin':269}]];

console.log(sort_kvs(input[0]));
```

Comment: I want to ask why are you subtracting a.purity and b.purity.

Comment: That's the `return the difference` part - get the `purity` property of one object, and the `purity` property of the other object, and return the difference to determine which should come first.

Comment: If the difference in a and b is negative then a is smaller than b and vice versa. this will explain https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp#midcontentadcontainer